# VBA - Como identificar última linha ativa, quando tem fórmula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

O código abaixo identifica a última linha ativa da planilha.

Quando a coluna A é preenchida manualmente ela funciona. Mas quando coloco uma fórmula para preencher essa coluna de acordo com outra planilha. O código não para de executar.

Por exemplo: a planilha tem dados até a linha 46, porém a execução só para quando chega na linha 78, até onde arrastei a fórmula.

```
lUltimaLinhaAtiva = Worksheets("Painel").Cells(Worksheets("Painel").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Selecione todas as linhas em "branco" e exclua-as para ver, deverá funcionar.

Comment: Não posso fazer isso. Pois dependendo do filtro que eu usar na outra planilha o número de linhas pode aumentar ou diminuir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando uma planilha de dados chamada "Dados" e a com fórmulas "Painel"

Insira uma fórmula de condição `=SE()` na fórmula para deixar a linha vazia se não houver dados na planilha "Dados" com:

`=SE(Dados!A1, FÓRMULA_CÁLCULO(A1), "")`

Em que `FÓRMULA_CÁLCULO()` é a fórmula utilizada para os cálculos na planilha "Painel"

Então a Última Linha pode ser obtida com:

```
Dim lUltimaLinhaAtiva  As Long
lUltimaLinhaAtiva = Worksheets("Painel").Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, False).Row
```